# Filter a list of tuples on two conditions

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuples which look like this:

```
let tups = [("AA","BB",1),
            ("AA","CC",2),
            ("AA","BB",3),
            ("VV","RR",4),
            ("XX","TT",5),
            ("BB","BB",6)]
```

I'd like to filter out tuples only where the first element is `AA` and the second element is `BB`. I was attempting to use:

```
filter (\(x,y,_) -> x /= "AA" && y /= "BB") tups
```

The above command removes any tuple where the first element is an "AA" OR the second element is a "BB". Therefore, the output is:

```
[("VV","RR",4), ("XX","TT",5)]
```

How can I create a filter function to ONLY remove tuples where the first elemet is "AA" and the second elements is "BB"? The correct output sholuld be:

```
[("AA","CC",2), ("VV","RR",4), ("XX","TT",5), ("BB","BB",6)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can read on the documentation, [filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:filter) returns the list of those elements that satisfy the predicate. This means that your predicate has to return `True` only for the elements you're going to keep.

So, by rephrasing your request, we want to keep all those triples whose first element is different from "AA" or the second is different from "BB":

```
filter (\(x,y,_)-> x /= "AA" || y /= "BB" ) tups
```

Comment: Great answer! But how can I use a predicate that my function gets as argument?

Answer (score 8):

Boolean algebra. The ones you want to remove satisfy the condition

```
x == "AA" && y == "BB"
```

Boolean algebra states that

```
¬(x and y) = ¬x or ¬y
```

Therefore the condition for your lambda should be

```
x /= "AA" || y /= "BB"
```

because `filter` keeps everything for which the supplied predicate returns `True`.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like something that makes your intent more clear, try:

```
filter (\(x,y,_) -> not $ x == "AA" && y == "BB") tups
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filter (\(x,y,_) -> x /= "AA" || y /= "BB") tups
```

Will do what you want it to do. You're mixing up the `&&` and `||` operators. Filter will get everything where the predicate is true, so anything which does not have `"AA"` gets returned, and everything where `y` isn't "BB" is returned.